# How do i find the third longest word in string

Tags: c#

Hello im a bit stuck i dont know how to find the third longest word in a string, i have got my code to find the longest but i cant manage to get it to find the third longest. any help?

```
public void longestWord()
    {
        string sentance, word;
        word = " ";
        char[] a = new char[] { ' ' };
        sentance = textBox1.Text;  //<--string here


        foreach (string s1 in sentance.Split(a))
        {
            if (word.Length < s1.Length)
            {
                word = s1;
            }
        }
        label9.Text = ("The longest word is " + word + " and its length is " + word.Length + " characters long");
    }
```

P.S an example of the string im testing is:

  1.

DarkN3ss is my most experienced provider of Windows based business solutions. I focus on delivering my business value in best possible understanding of this technologies and directions.
DarkN3ss recognising me as an “elite business partner” for implementing solutions based on my capabilities and experience with Windows and Linux products.

Comment: `var third = sentance.Split(new string[]{' '}).OrderBy(s=>s).Skip(2).Take(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** To get all the third largest words

```
   string[] splitStr = sentence.Split(' ');

   if (splitStr.Length > 2)
   {
        List<int> allLengths = splitStr.Select(x => x.Length).Distinct().ToList();

        int thirdLargestWordLength = allLengths.OrderByDescending(x => x)
                                               .Skip(2).Distinct().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

        if (splitStr[0].Length != thirdLargestWordLength && 
         splitStr[1].Length != thirdLargestWordLength)
         {

            string[] theThirdLargestWords = splitStr.Where(x => x.Length == thirdLargestWordLength)
                                                                  .ToArray();


             if (theThirdLargestWords.Length == 1)
             {
                label9.Text = "The third longest word is " + theThirdLargestWords[0];
             }
             else
             {
                string words = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < theThirdLargestWords.Length; i++)
                {
                   if (i == 0)
                   {
                     words = theThirdLargestWords[i];
                }
               //else if ((i + 1) == theThirdLargestWords.Length)
               //{
               //   words += " and " + theThirdLargestWords[i];
               //}
                else
                {
                    words += ", " + theThirdLargestWords[i];
                }
             }

             label9.Text = "The third longest words are " + words;
        }
      }
   }
```

I commented out the "and" part as i'm not sure if you want that in your string. I also added the first if statement so you don't get an error if you have less then 3 words.

Comment: now say i have 2 words in the string that are equal how can i get them both to show? instead of one?

Comment: yea, but how would i get it so it takes the 2 that = 11 characters?

Comment: You just need to iterate through it. Ill put up an example

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().ToString()` can throw

Comment: @asawyer, it won't throw an error as it will only get there if there is at least 3 records. The only issue I can see is if there is 3 of the same words "Hello Hello Hello" It will return all 3. Ill put an if statement to fix that up.

Comment: @MVCKarl No, it will throw if the input has less then three words of if input is null (but that's more obvious). Besides that, my point in a round about way is that is doesn't make sense to call `.ToString()` on a method that returns a string `(FirstOrDefault)`.

Comment: @asawyer okay you are talking about my original answer instead of my complete answer which has the error checking. You are right it wouldn't need the .ToString() part. Cheers

Comment: @MVCKarl hey this is what im having trouble with, this is the string in a textbox, i added the STRING to the original question at the top^, you will see the problem when you try it :)

Comment: @DarkN3ss , just try my full code and it will return technologies, implementing and capabilities

Comment: @MVCKarl yea thats right but i want it to return all the 3rd longest words which are in this case 11 characters long.(if you understand what i mean)

Comment: @MVCKarl a cheap way to fix it is to change "Skip(2)" to "Skip(4)" but then it wont be the same for other strings i might change it to

Comment: @DarkN3ss alright I added alllengths list and changed the thirdLargestWordLength linq query. Some words will come up with . so just using something like sentence = sentence.Replace(".", ""); before the split

Answer (score 2):

how about using linq?

```
sentance.Split(' ').OrderByDescending(w => w.Length).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()
```

in a function :

```
public void nthLongestWord(int index = 0)
{
    string word = null;
    if(index <= 0)
    {
        word = sentance.Split(' ').OrderByDescending(w => w.Length).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        word = sentance.Split(' ').OrderByDescending(w => w.Length).Skip(index - 1).FirstOrDefault();
    }


    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(word))
    {
        label9.Text = ("The longest word is " + word + " and its length is " + word.Length + " characters long");
    }
    else 
    {
        // display something else?
    }
}
```

Comment: it says: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and i added the Linq reference.? any help?

Comment: @DarkN3ss You'd need to format this properly in an ide ... I didn't test this. Its probably a case sensitive issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to make minimal changes to your current code, then what you should do is store the three longest words (i.e., instead of `word`, have `word1`, `word2`, and `word3`, or an array if you'd prefer).

Then, in your if statement, set word3=word2, word2=word1, and word1=s1.

That way, the third largest word will end up in `word3`.

Not the most efficient, but you'll be able to keep your current code, to a degree.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel confortable using a temporary array, you should copy your words there, sort them and take the 3rd longest one.

Comment: A `SortedList` would probably be better then an array.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might have compile error, but just to give you an idea.

var words = sentence.split();

words.OrderBy (w => w.length ).ToArray ()[2]